# Detect if item exist on creation of a new record in radgrid

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting an error in this code every time I create a new item.
"Argument out of range exception" on line 4.

```
protected void RadGrid1_ItemCreated(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item is GridEditableItem && e.Item.IsInEditMode)
    {
        GridEditableItem editedItem = e.Item as GridEditableItem;
        string recordIDcreateDir = editedItem.GetDataKeyValue("TransazioneID").ToString();
        string subPath = "Allegati\\" + recordIDcreateDir; 
        bool isExists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath(subPath));
        if (!isExists)
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(subPath));
........
```

obviously on creation of a new record the "TransazioneID" value is not there yet and this is why I get the error.
But How can I make it conditional to the existence of the record with an if statement.
I tried

```
 if(editedItem.GetDataKeyValue("TransazioneID").ToString()== null);
and....
 if(editedItem.GetDataKeyValue("TransazioneID")!= null); and several others....
```

but witout any success. How can I catch something on that statement to avoid execution of those lines on item creation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GridTableView.DataKeyNames`](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/p_telerik_web_ui_gridtableview_datakeynames.html):

```
if (editedItem.OwnerTableView.DataKeyNames.Contains("TransazioneID")) { ... }
```

---

From Telerik's [docs](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/allmembers_t_telerik_web_ui_grideditableitem.html), noted under `GridEditableItem.GetDataKeyValue`:

> Get the DataKeyValues from the owner GridTableView with the corresponding item ItemIndex and keyName. The keyName should be one of the specified in the DataKeyNames array